# regex to replace content in two lines if it repeats

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a big xml file with 8 million lines. Some of them have parts that I want to remove, but only if they are the same.

```
<sector x="4092" y="4024" x_size="4" y_size="4" >
</sector>
<sector x="4092" y="4028" x_size="4" y_size="4" >
</sector>
<sector x="4092" y="4032" x_size="4" y_size="4" >
belladonna:1|
</sector>
<sector x="4092" y="4036" x_size="4" y_size="4" >
</sector>
<sector x="4092" y="4040" x_size="4" y_size="4" >
</sector>
<sector x="4092" y="4044" x_size="4" y_size="4" >
</sector>
<sector x="4092" y="4048" x_size="4" y_size="4" >
</sector>
<sector x="4092" y="4052" x_size="4" y_size="4" >
</sector>
<sector x="4092" y="4056" x_size="4" y_size="4" >
sage:1|
</sector>
```

I can select the content between the sectors tag, but I want to remove them if they are empty.

Using this regex: `<sector[\s\S]*?">\n<\/sector>` I can select the content but they include the line, I only want to match the sectors tag without the content between them.

So the example above will remove only the ones without text between them.
Like this:

```
<sector x="4092" y="4032" x_size="4" y_size="4" >
belladonna:1|
</sector>
<sector x="4092" y="4056" x_size="4" y_size="4" >
sage:1|
</sector>
```

Comment: If you have xml file with or without 8 millions of lines, don't use notepad++ to edit it. Use one of the many tools for xml.

Comment: Yeah I saw that notepad++ crashes a lot, using sublime text now.

Answer (score -1):

Okay, found a good regex:

`<sector x=".*" y=".*" x_size="4" y_size="4" >\n<\/sector>`

Comment: Is there a setting for nongreedy matches that you're using? Btw, not my downvote.